# what is the best way to run a batch job using Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have worked on Symfony 1.1 and http://www.lampjunkie.com/2008/04/how-to-use-symfony-and-cron/ is a doc I have come across online. For any batch job, it is required to load root directory path and make DB connections.

Is there any ready format or any plugin to create or run a batch file in Symfony 2?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by creating a console command.

Check this : http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console.html

Then you can use a crontab to call it